# Telegram bot send message in certain hour in ruby

Tags: ruby, chat, bots, telegram-bot, reminders

I would create a telegram bot in ruby that send a message in a determinate hour i decide. For example. It's 8 am and the bot send a message "Good morning". Of course every morning at the same time. It could be a kind of reminder. I can get the time in this way:

```
time = Time.now.strftime("%H:%M")
```

And i know that to send a message i can use the Telegram API like:

```
bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Hi")
```

I use this code when i have an interaction between the bot and a user. For example:

```
Telegram::Bot::Client.run(token) do |bot|

  bot.listen do |message|
    case message.text
    when "hi", 'hi@myBot'
      bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "Hi, #{message.from.first_name}")
    end
....
....
```

but I don't know how do what i need because if i want to send a message i need the `chat.id` and in this case i get it only when i have an interaction with a user. So, is it possibile send a message for example when it's 8 am without any user interaction?

Comment: The only way to send a message without interaction is to hardcode chat id. Do you want to send a message to a certain chat?

Comment: The bot could be in many groups. I can maybe store the chat id in some way and then use it but i don't know if could be the right way. Have you any idea how solve my problem?

Comment: You have two options: store ids and send a message by a cron task or create a worker after every message received. Both of them requires user interaction.

Comment: So, shortly, I can't do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [crono](https://github.com/plashchynski/crono) gem to perform asynchronous tasks.

`Crono.perform(YourJob).every 1.day, at: {hour: 8, min: 00}`

Comment: I have never use crono and it's my first experiment with ruby. Can you please explain how can I use it? Thank you very much

Comment: Just go the the gem git repository I linked above. The usage of the gem is described in details there.

Comment: Did I help you with your problem? Can you accept my answer? @End.Game